# CSS - flex grow height and enable overflow

Tags: css, flexbox

Problem: Cannot enable overflow on a flex grow child.

Example:

- Div 1 flex grows to content.
- Div 2 flex grows to fill available
- Div 2.1 sits within Div 2 & is taller, so I want to enable overflow, but it keeps growing beyond & extending the body height.
- Div 3 flex grows to content

**How do I enable div 2.1 to grow to the size of Div 2 but also enable overflow?**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="flex-fitcontents">
    <p> "Fit contents" </p>
 </div>
 <div class="flex-fillremaining">
    <p> "Take up remaining space" </p>
    <div class="flex-fillparent">
        <p> "Fill parent" </p>
        <p> "Content" </p>        
        <p> "Content" </p>
        <p> "Content" </p>
        <p> "Content" </p>
        <p> "Content" </p>
        <p> "Content" </p>
        <p> "Content" </p>
        <p> "Content" </p>
        <p> "Content" </p>
        <p> "This content should be in the overflow" </p>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="flex-fitcontents">
    <p> "Fit contents" </p>      
 </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.flex-fitcontents {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    background-color: blue;
}
.flex-fillremaining {
    position: relative;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background-color: red;
}
.flex-fillparent {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bt4Lqvpk/)

Comment: You mean something like this https://jsfiddle.net/cw0bhoa9/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly, you mean something like in the following example. Setting height in `flex-fillparent` solves the problem.

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-fitcontents {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

.flex-fillremaining {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.flex-fillparent {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-fitcontents">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eleifend bibendum rutrum. Duis cursus eros eget ornare efficitur. Aliquam pellentesque, arcu sed euismod pulvinar, quam enim commodo est, sit amet tristique justo arcu non tortor.
      In nec dignissim tortor. Pellentesque nibh justo, suscipit ut tempor at, mollis vitae purus. Aenean sollicitudin scelerisque blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-fillremaining">
    <p> "Take up remaining space" </p>
    <div class="flex-fillparent">
      <p> "Fill parent" </p>
      <p> "Content" </p>
      <p> "Content" </p>
      <p> "Content" </p>
      <p> "Content" </p>
      <p> "Content" </p>
      <p> "Content" </p>
      <p> "Content" </p>
      <p> "Content" </p>
      <p> "Content" </p>
      <p> "Content" </p>
      <p> "Content" </p>
      <p> "Content" </p>
      <p> "Content" </p>
      <p> "Content" </p>
      <p> "Content" </p>
      <p> "This content should be in the overflow" </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-fitcontents">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eleifend bibendum rutrum. Duis cursus eros eget ornare efficitur. Aliquam pellentesque, arcu sed euismod pulvinar, quam enim commodo est, sit amet tristique justo arcu non tortor.
      In nec dignissim tortor. Pellentesque nibh justo, suscipit ut tempor at, mollis vitae purus. Aenean sollicitudin scelerisque blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without setting the height of fillparent? It seems like this solution makes the overflow box very small, and doesn't fill the fill remaining box.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding overflow auto to flex-fillremaining, so that its children have a scroll bar.

```css
.flex-fillremaining {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
}
```