# CSS/Tailwind Getting flex-grow child to scroll on overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow, tailwind-css

I am having trouble getting the content in a div to scroll on overflow. I've been playing around with it most of the day and haven't really got anywhere! I am using Tailwind for layout. Before I go into what I've tried, here's a link to a Tailwind playground demonstrating my issue: https://play.tailwindcss.com/S4U9ewEu98. I've made a couple of comments, I'm using React behind the scenes, so that's just the pasted output from Chrome, which is why there's a bit of a hack to set some styles on the divs with rsw class names.

I've looked here: [CSS - flex grow height and enable overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64050371/css-flex-grow-height-and-enable-overflow) and, indeed, if I set a manual height on the `div.tw-overflow-scroll` on line 45, such as adding the `tw-h-80` class, then it scrolls and only takes up that height (equivalent to `height: 20rem;`). However, I want this to completely fill any remaining space. If I replace that with `tw-h-full`, which is the equivalent of adding `height: 100%;` So it seems as if it's having an issue with percentage heights. I have indicated in the playground which lines to comment out to see what the layout should look like. It works fine when there's no overflowing content!

I've also read on other articles on here that adding a `min-height: 0px` to the flex child containing the overflowing container fixes it. Alas, it doesn't seem to. I've been tearing my hair out all day as surely this is easier than I'm finding it? I'd appreciate it if somebody could offer some assistance!

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is the opposite.

In line 41 `<div class="tw-flex-grow tw-min-h-0">`

replace to: `<div class="tw-flex-grow tw-h-0 tw-min-h-full tw-overflow-y-auto">`

https://play.tailwindcss.com/UHWAvyVrUN

Answer (score 0):

Here you go
https://play.tailwindcss.com/IUMn8ZCpvh

You missed a couple of `tw-h-full` and one `tw-min-h-0`.

Comment: Thanks for that. However, although it makes the list scrollable, the last item in the list is still cut off the bottom, and so are the buttons underneath. Here's a bit of a better illustration of what it should look like, but instead of a full height list, I've added a manual height to the scrollable container: https://play.tailwindcss.com/uBJgz33rI0